# HTMLからファイルをダウンロードできない

Tags: python, html, bottle

```
<a href="/tmp/kMEHGrEW1Ch0rCyerXjGkJxELhA6Dgfw/kMEHGrEW1Ch0rCyerXjGkJxELhA6Dgfw.zip">ファイルダウンロード</a>`
```

というリンクをhtmlに埋めこみドキュメントルートから`tmp/kMEHGrEW1Ch0rCyerXjGkJxELhA6Dgfw/kMEHGrEW1Ch0rCyerXjGkJxELhA6Dgfw.zip`に存在するファイルをダウンロードさせようとましたが、`404 NotFound`エラーが出てしまいます。
urlは`http://localhost:8080/tmp/kMEHGrEW1Ch0rCyerXjGkJxELhA6Dgfw/kMEHGrEW1Ch0rCyerXjGkJxELhA6Dgfw.zip`となっていて、ファイルも存在しますができません。なぜでしょうか。

追記

OS:Mac OS X
Webサーバー:PythonのBottleフレームワークのテスト用サーバー
tmpディレクトリのパーミッション:drwxr-xr-x
kMEHGrEW1Ch0rCyerXjGkJxELhA6Dgfwのパーミッション:drwxr-xr-x
kMEHGrEW1Ch0rCyerXjGkJxELhA6Dgfw.zipのパーミッション:-rw-r--r--

Comment: OSとかWebサーバとか、そのディレクトリのアクセス権とか。
もう少し情報を書かないと。

Comment: パーミッションなどを追記させて頂きました。

Comment: すぐ確認できる環境がないのであれですが、/etcの下（直下ではなかったかも）のhttp.confだかのApache関係のファイルで、公開する際のルートディレクトリの指定があったように思います。ユーザ別に指定するファイルもあったような。

初期状態で、"/Users/(username)/Sites/"などが指定されていると思います。
そこに追加すればアクセスはできるようになるんじゃないかと。

自分がいじってた頃のは10.5.8なので今とは違っているかも。
曖昧ですみません。他の方の具体的な回答期待しています。

Comment: おそらくルーティングの設定が関係しているものと思います。実行しているpythonスクリプトを提示できますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

解決しました。
ルートを追加し、Force Downloadという仕組みを使うことで実装できました。

```html
@app.route('/tmp/<dirname:path>/<filename:path>', method='GET')
def download(dirname, filename):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'/tmp/'+dirname+'/'
    return static_file(filename, root=root)
```

参考URL:http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/bottle-docs.pdf